# regular expression - grep, sed, awk - processing large text file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep, find

I've been using a text editor to do my regular expression work.  It works great but now I'm now the sample file is 10GB size so it chokes the text editor.

**what do you recommend using and would you have some samples or websites to reference?**

I was looking at this is what I found with people using it for many things

- find - is a file search
- grep - is a line based search
- awk - is a find and replace search
- sed - is a programming language search

What I'm looking for is:

something you can put regular expressions: (.*), [a-z] then

Text file:

```
some-text-file : threw this cat and then sat on the mat  
some-other-text-file : the quick brown flew free then the fox fell
yet-another-text-file : i hope this explains this and that thoroughly
```

desire

- find the line that starts with some and find "then" and take everything from then to the end of the sentence
- output Subject: if some is found put "Some:
- output in the same line if "then" is found show all the text from that point to the end of the sentence.

regular expression (which of those could just output the value rather than modify it using this syntax?

also I would like to match multiple lines and return match texted only.

```
find: (^some)(.*)(then)(.*)
return: Subject: some then: \4
```

Result: (search results not file modification)

```
Subject: some Result: then sat on the mat  
Subject: some Result: then the fox fell
yet-another-text-file : i hope this explains this and that thoroughly
```

Comment: how is the third line matched anything?

Comment: So what have you tried and what is your problem?

Comment: Include a line like `they ran then they walked then they sat` in your sample input/output so we can see if you want the output to start from the first or the last `then` on the line. And fix your requirements to say you want `Subject: some then:` or `Subject: some Result: then` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

This will work efficiently on any size input file:

```
$ sed 's/^some.*then\(.*\)/Subject: some then:\1/' file
Subject: some then: sat on the mat
Subject: some then: the fox fell
yet-another-text-file : i hope this explains this and that thoroughly
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and include sample input/output that the above doesn't work for.